# Sort arrays using lambda

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want revers-sort java8.
I don't want use stream.

Here is an example:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I want it like this: `{5, 4, 3, 2, 1};`

So my code is this

```
Arrays.sort(a, (o1, o2) -> o2 - o1);

Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) ->Integer.compare(b ,a));
```

But I get an error message:

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'T', 'T'

How can I reverse sort and sort?

Is there a better way?

Comment: It may be because of missing brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
int[] sortedArray = Arrays.stream(a)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
```

if you use Integer data type then even easier

```
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: i wanna use lambda

Comment: @JavaMe do you actually know what lambda is? Where it should be placed in the case of the stream solution?

Comment: try this then: `Comparator<Integer> c = (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a, b);`

Comment: thank you but i'm worring about performance stream code

Comment: @JavaMe I am worried about how are you going to use a lambda without a stream. Just curious...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`, but you pass to it a primitive array. Primitive types cannot be used in place of generic type parameters.

If you use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`, your code will work.

```
Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> b - a);
```

or

```
Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(b,a));
```

Comment: int[][] con = new int[1][1];

Arrays.sort(con, (a, b) -> a[1] == b[1] ? a[0] - b[0] : a[1] - b[1]);
This is working what is diffrence?

Comment: @JavaMe `int[][]` is an array whose elements are arrays (`int[]`), and arrays are reference types, so they can be used in place of generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

```
Integer[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(a, (o1, o2) -> o2 - o1);
```

This is the method signature which doesn't works for primitive type.

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c);
```

You might be wondering why it works for `int[]`. Its because there is another method which accepts primitive type `int[]`

```
public static void sort(int[] a);
```

Comment: int[][] con = new int[1][1];

Arrays.sort(con, (a, b) -> a[1] == b[1] ? a[0] - b[0] : a[1] - b[1]);
This is working what is diffrence?

Comment: It's because int[] is an object of `java.lang.reflect.Array`. And int[][] become Array[].

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Integer instead of int it would be great simply use the below code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Arrays.sort(a, (o1, o2) -> o2 - o1);

        for(Integer i: a)
            System.out.print(i+", ");
    }
}
```

Its output will be:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
```